# After merging documents, compensate page numbering manually (of ToC)

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering

I have a PDF that I want to append to three other PDFs (of one page each). It works with a command I found [here](https://www.linux.com/news/software/applications/8229-putting-together-pdf-files) only of course, page numbering (the ToC) isn't right. So, how could I tell it to add a digit before start counting "for real"? (To compensate for the pages I added!)

Note, I don't have the LaTeX source of the "head" documents so my bet is to manually change the start point in the "tail" document, for which I do have the LaTeX source. The ToC is there, too.

Comment: `\setcounter{page}{4}`, assuming that your text begins on page `4`.

Comment: @PeterGrill: OK - I managed to do it with another [method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2739710).

Comment: @PeterGrill: No, this solution is better; the `\usepackage{pdfpages}` conflicts with my other stuff. Thanks.

Comment: I thought your question was about how to get the correct page numbering, not about inserting the pages into your document. Yes, `pdfpages` is the way to go to incorporate them into your doc.

Comment: @PeterGrill: \*Laughter\*! Sorry about the confusion. Your first interpretation, and answer, was correct. I thought about doing it another way but it turned out not to work (collided with something) so I switched back to this method, and with the `\setcounter` you suggested it works great. Write it as an answer if you'd like me to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\setcounter{page}{<n>}` to reset the page counter to `<n>`. So, assuming that your text begins on page 4 use `\setcounter{page}{4}`.

To insert PDF documents, you could use [the `pdfpages` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages).